# C++: partial specialization of template template classes

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

The following code:

```
using namespace std;

template <typename X>
class Goo {};


template <typename X>
class Hoo {};


template <class A, template <typename> class B = Goo >
struct Foo {
  B<A> data;
  void foo1();
  void foo2();

};


template <typename A>
void Foo<A>::foo1() { cout << "foo1 for Goo" << endl;}


int main() {
  Foo<int> a;
  a.foo1();

}
```

gives me a compiler error:

```
test.cc:18: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'struct Foo<A, Goo>'
test.cc:11: error: declaration of 'struct Foo<A, Goo>'
```

Why can't I partially specialize foo1() ?  If this is not the way, how do I do this?

I have another question: what if I want foo2() to be defined only for A=int, B=Hoo
and not for any other combination, how do I do that?

Comment: This isn't a partial specialization, Foo takes two parameters and you only specify one in `Foo<A>::foo1`.

Comment: @BoPersson: I think I am partially specializing. The second template parameter is by default Goo.

Comment: And what is X in Goo<X>. Goo is template taking a parameter X. Where is it specified?

Comment: @jmucchiello: By the Goo<A> data member in Foo<A>.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Function templates may only be *fully* specialized, not partially.

Member functions of class templates are automatically function templates, and they may indeed be specialized, but only fully:

```
template <>
void Foo<int, Goo>::foo1() { }  // OK
```

You can partially specialise the entire *class* and then define it anew:

```
template <typename A>
struct Foo<A, Goo>
{
  // ...
};
```

(See 14.7.3 for details.)

Comment: I don't think he's even trying to specialize. Edit: Ah right, by "partial specialization" he wants to omit one of the parameters.

Comment: So there is no way to partially specialize a member method of a template class, without specializing the whole class itself?

Comment: @user231536: No, indeed. Here's a [similar, previous answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7517290/596781).

Answer (score 1):

The template still has two parameters, and you must write something like this:

```
template <typename A, template <typename> class B>
void Foo<A,B>::foo1() { cout << "foo1" << endl;}
```

The default has been specified, and only needs to be specified once. From then on, it's just like any other two-parameter template. This code will apply no matter what B is (defaulted or otherwise). If you then wish to specify different behaviour for a particular B, *then* you do specialization of the class, not just of a method.

(**Heavily edited**)

Comment: I think that some combination of @KerreckSB's answer, and maybe mine, might be correct. I'm not sure what the ultimate goal is. Ultimately, I think a totally-unspecialized `foo1()` will need to be implemented sooner or later, like the one I have written.